# Deciles or other quantile rank for Pyspark column

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark DF with multiple numeric columns and I want to, for each column calculate the decile or other quantile rank for that row based on each variable.

This is simple for pandas as we can create a new column for each variable using the qcut function to assign the value 0 to n-1 for 'q' as in pd.qcut(x,q=n).

How can this be done in pyspark? I have tried the following but clearly the break points are not unique between these thirds. I want to get the lower 1/3 of the data assigned 1, the next 1/3 assigned 2 and the top 1/3 assigned 3. I want to be able to change this and perhaps use 1/10, 1/32 etc

```
w =  Window.partitionBy(data.var1).orderBy(data.var1)
d2=df.select(
    "var1",
     ntile(3).over(w).alias("ntile3")
)


agged=d2.groupby('ntile3').agg(F.min("var1").alias("min_var1"),F.max("var1").alias("max_var1"),F.count('*'))
agged.show()

+------+--------+--------+--------+
|ntile3|min_var1|max_var1|count(1)|
+------+--------+--------+--------+
|     1|     0.0|   210.0|  517037|
|     3|     0.0|   206.0|  516917|
|     2|     0.0|   210.0|  516962|
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[QuantileDiscretizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#quantilediscretizer) from `'pyspark.ml.feature'` can be used.

```
values = [(0.1,), (0.4,), (1.2,), (1.5,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(values, ["values"])
qds = QuantileDiscretizer(numBuckets=2,
...     inputCol="values", outputCol="buckets", relativeError=0.01, handleInvalid="error")
bucketizer = qds.fit(df)
bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(df).transform(df).show()

+------+-------+
|values|buckets|
+------+-------+
|   0.1|    0.0|
|   0.4|    1.0|
|   1.2|    1.0|
|   1.5|    1.0|
+------+-------+
```

Comment: While using this code, I get the following error on the last line: 'A Bucketizer object does not have an attribute fit. Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.'

Comment: OK, found it. Someone edited your code and replaced it with an incorrect code!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `percent_rank` from [pyspark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.functions) with a window function. For instance for computing deciles you can do:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import ceil, percent_rank

w =  Window.orderBy(data.var1)
data.select('*', ceil(10 * percent_rank().over(w)).alias("decile"))
```

By doing so you first compute the percent_rank, and then you multiply this by 10 and take the upper integer. Consequently, all values with a percent_rank between 0 and 0.1 will be added to decile 1, all values with a percent_rank between 0.1 and 0.2 will be added to decile 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the accepted answer `fit` is called two times. Thus change from

```
bucketizer = qds.fit(df)
bucketizer.setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(df).transform(df).show()
```

to

```
qds.setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(df).transform(df).show()
```

Comment: If you look at the history of the edits on the code, the original code was correct, an idiot has edited it to this incorrect code!